# MatTable not refreshing on updates

Tags: angular, angular-material, mat-table

Im trying to refresh a `mat-table` view after doing an update operation on it's data. However, the table view is only refreshing correctly the first time I do an update. Every subsequent update operation is delayed by 1 action like so:

1. Update row 1 -> nothing happens
2. Update row 2 -> row 1 gets updated
3. Update row 3 -> row 2 gets updated

and so on...

The table is loaded using an http.get service to get the data. 
The update operation calls a http.post service to save the data, and subsequently calls the `refreshData()` method. Both services are working as intended.

I'm using `ChangeDetectorRef`to force change detection.

**Component:**

```js
dataSource: MatTableDataSource<IRegion> = new MatTableDataSource();

@ViewChild(MatSort) set content(sort: MatSort) {
    this.dataSource.sort = sort;
};

constructor(private regionService: RegionService, private changeDetectorRefs: ChangeDetectorRef) {}

ngOnInit() {
    this.populateRegions();
}

refreshData(){
    this.populateRegions();
}

populateRegions(){
    this.regionService.getRegions().subscribe({
        next: regions => {
            this.dataSource.data = regions;
            this.changeDetectorRefs.detectChanges();
        }
    });
}
```

What am I doing wrong here?

Comment: Do you reach to `this.dataSource.data = regions` after first update?

Comment: @MaihanNijat yes. I've used logs to check everything (removed them here to keep the code simple), and its working as intended. It's only the view that is not updating.

Comment: *and subsequently calls the refreshData()* - please show how it does that

Comment: Ok... I found out what the problem was. Both the save and get services are http requests to a backend server. Since they are called almost simultaneously (post -> get) the get service reads the data before the data gets saved. I've added a delay between the two and now it's working fine.

Comment: @DanielAndré adding a delay might not be a good idea. It might take longer than expected. Wait for one call and after completion, call another one.

Answer (score 2):

Use `RenderRows()` method on the reference of `mat-table`:

```
@ViewChild(MatTable, {static: false}) table : MatTable
this.table.renderRows()
```

Or recreate the data source object:

```
populateRegions(){
    this.regionService.getRegions().subscribe({
        next: regions => {
            this.dataSource = new MatTableDataSource(regions);
            this.changeDetectorRefs.detectChanges();
        }
    });
}
```

Comment: Same behaviour. It works the first time, but every edit after that has a delay of 1 operation. Tried it in different browsers as well.